Ubuntu 22.04 - sound not playing - dummy output only
Sound is not playing any more on my Ubuntu 22.04 / Gnome 42.9 (Dell Precision 5570).
Settings -> sound, as well as pavucontrol only show "Dummy Output". Bluetooth does not connect to my remote speaker.
Here are some diagnostics:
$ lsb_release -cdir
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy

$ uname -r
6.8.0-45-generic

$ hwinfo --sound
20: PCI 1f.3: 0403 Audio device                                 
  [Created at pci.386]
  Unique ID: nS1_.eQx3+cEVar6
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3
  SysFS BusID: 0000:00:1f.3
  Hardware Class: sound
  Model: "Intel Audio device"
  Vendor: pci 0x8086 "Intel Corporation"
  Device: pci 0x51c8 
  SubVendor: pci 0x1028 "Dell"
  SubDevice: pci 0x0b1a 
  Revision: 0x01
  Driver: "snd_hda_intel"
  Driver Modules: "snd_hda_intel"
  Memory Range: 0x6289290000-0x6289293fff (rw,non-prefetchable)
  Memory Range: 0x6289000000-0x62890fffff (rw,non-prefetchable)
  IRQ: 222 (885 events)
  Module Alias: "pci:v00008086d000051C8sv00001028sd00000B1Abc04sc03i80"
  Driver Info #0:
    Driver Status: snd_hda_intel is active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe snd_hda_intel"
  Driver Info #1:
    Driver Status: snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl is active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl"
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown

$ lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Audio
0000:00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH-P High Definition Audio Controller [8086:51c8] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:0b1a]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel

$ lsmod | grep snd_hda_intel
snd_hda_intel          61440  0
snd_intel_dspcfg       36864  3 snd_hda_intel,snd_sof,snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_hda_codec         204800  6 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_sof_intel_hda
snd_hda_core          139264  9 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_ext_core,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_sof_intel_hda
snd_pcm               192512  11 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,soundwire_intel,snd_sof,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_sof_utils,snd_hda_core,snd_pcm_dmaengine
snd                   143360  15 snd_ctl_led,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_sof,snd_timer,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi

$ aplay -l # sorry for the french version
**** Liste des périphériques matériels PLAYBACK ****
carte 0 : PCH [HDA Intel PCH], périphérique 0 : ALC289 Analog [ALC289 Analog]
  Sous-périphériques : 1/1
  Sous-périphérique #0 : subdevice #0
carte 0 : PCH [HDA Intel PCH], périphérique 3 : HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Sous-périphériques : 1/1
  Sous-périphérique #0 : subdevice #0
carte 0 : PCH [HDA Intel PCH], périphérique 7 : HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Sous-périphériques : 1/1
  Sous-périphérique #0 : subdevice #0
carte 0 : PCH [HDA Intel PCH], périphérique 8 : HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Sous-périphériques : 1/1
  Sous-périphérique #0 : subdevice #0
carte 0 : PCH [HDA Intel PCH], périphérique 9 : HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Sous-périphériques : 1/1
  Sous-périphérique #0 : subdevice #0

$ alsactl -v
alsactl version 1.2.6

$ pulseaudio --version
pulseaudio 16.1

Following some advices from forums, I have re-installed some stuff:
$ sudo apt install -y alsa-base linux-sound-base pulseaudio pulseaudio-utils

Also, I have tried to add options snd-hda-intel model=auto to /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf, or the same with model=generic or dmic_detect=0.
Nothing works.
Could you help me please?
